# Confusion about this in callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am really confused about the value of this in callbacks, well I know that the value of this is always taken from where it was called, but here in the below code, i can't figure out what's happening.

```
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    let user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
        } else {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        }
    })
});
```

I was watching a tutorial of node js with mongoose, so the instructor said:
In the context of this callback function, the word **this** refers to the object, which is

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

shouldn't the `user = this` here refer to Node Global Object instead of that object?

so I'm really confused how this happens, for Example, if I try to mimic this code behaviour in simple JavaScript.

```
function UserSchema() {
    this.pre = function(cb) {
        return cb();
    }
}

function Bycrypt() {
    this.hash = function(cb) {
        return cb();
    }
}

userSchema.pre(function() {
    var user = this;
    bycrypt.hash(function() {
        console.log(user)
    })
});
```

this will log user as the **Window** Object because the callback function was called in the context of Window.

well, I know that it's a weird question to ask.

Comment: Usage of below answers in your code demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e9p3677c/

Comment: Answer updated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486224/1636522 :-)

Answer (score 3):

`this` in JavaScript functions refers to execution context and in a case of normal (not ES6-specific "arrow" function) normally equals to context, function was called in. However "this" can be changed by e.g. using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods of the Function object to pass different value for `this`.

You can read, for example, [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on MDN for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a weird question at all, the `this` keyword is often a source of confusion because of its implicit nature :-) Anyway, I have no idea about how the `pre` function is implemented, but we can easily imagine something like that :

```js
schema = {
  whoami: "a schema"
};
schema.pre = function (cb) {
  return cb.call(this);
}
schema.pre(function () {
  console.log(this.whoami);
});
```

The `call` function is a JavaScript builtin that allows to change the default subject (`window`) of a function. Browsing the source code I have found something that seems to be the `pre` function (not 100% sure) : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L1138. As you can see they use the `apply` builtin which has the same effect as `call`. Let's see how they differ :

```js
function f(a, b) {
  console.log("I am", this.whoami);
  console.log("Arguments :", "[" + a + ", " + b + "]");
}

f.call({ whoami: "A" }, "b", "c");
f.apply({ whoami: "X" }, ["y", "z"]);
```

I believe that this can be a good starting point to investigate. I let you dive into the source code to find the nature of `this.s.hooks` and `this.queue(...)` :-)

Comment: well now things started to make some sense, but can you explain to me that if the context of `userSchema.pre` is to set to `userSchema`. then can't we directly pass `this.password` to `bcrypt.hash` inside the callback rather than having to store the reference of this inside a user variable here and then passing it to the  `bcrypt.hash`

Comment: @OsamaXäwãñz The problem is that `this` may refer to a different object inside the callback :-|

Comment: @OsamaXäwãñz I'm not sure to understand your question though :-|

Answer (score 1):

`this` binds to the call site of a function. It can also be bind to where you specify it to bind to using function methods like `call`, `apply`, and `bind`.

```js
function foo () {
  var a = 5;
  console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

foo(); // 2
```

With ES6 arrow function, `this` is bound to the lexical scope.